# load form half screen in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I would like to dock my form to the right (*max resolution height* and *max resolution width / 2*). I am using VB.NET and my code so far is:

```
  Dim scr As Screen = Screen.FromControl(Me)
  Me.Top = scr.WorkingArea.Top + scr.WorkingArea.Height - Me.Height
  Me.Left = scr.WorkingArea.Left + scr.WorkingArea.Width - Me.Width
```

Any ideas how to make my form half as big as my current resolution and to position it at the right side of the desktop (like when using windows-key + right arrow)?

Comment: Have a look at [DockPanel Suite](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dockpanelsuite/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to set the Width and Height as well, not just the position.  Be sure to do this *after* the window has been rescaled, the form's Load event is best:

```
Public Class Form1
    Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Dim work = Screen.FromControl(Me).WorkingArea
        Me.Top = work.Top
        Me.Left = work.Right - work.Width / 2
        Me.Width = work.Width / 2
        Me.Height = work.Height
        MyBase.OnLoad(e)
    End Sub
End Class
```

If you do this after the window has already been displayed then favor assigning the `Bounds` property instead, it will avoid the repaints.